# suma de input con resultado automatico

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario con 3 input donde se colocan algunas cantidades enteras o decimales.

Lo que quiero es que al ir colocando cantidades en cada input se vaya sumando con el otro sin necesidad de dar clic en un botón de calcular, sino que se muestre el resultado en otro input o en un label. Pero como las entidades son productos necesito que sume el valor del producto y no la cantidad.
ej:
gaseosa: $50
agua: $20
que ingrese en el input la cantidad de gaseosas o agua que quiere y que le muestre la suma de los precios y que no supere el monto de $100.
yo tengo una idea con esto.

````
<head>
    <title></title>
     <form id="contact-from" class="contact" name="contact-from" method="post" action="enviar1.php">
</head>

<body>
            <h2>FRUTAS SECAS</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  <cener>
            <div class="from-group">
            <br><li>Almendra carmel </li><BR>
            100 gr. - $130.00 <INPUT TYPE ="NUMBER" NAME ="producto01" id="producto01" onchange="sumar(this.value);"><br>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
            1 kilo - $1300.00 <INPUT TYPE ="NUMBER" NAME ="producto02" onchange="sumar(this.value);"><br>
            </div>

<script> 
    function sumar (valor) {
    var total = 0;  
    valor = parseInt(valor);
    
    total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
    
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
    
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
    
    document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
          if ( spTotal > 1500) {
    alert("Supero el monto");
    return true;
}
}

</script>
<span>Carrito: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
<button TYPE="SUBMIT" class="boton">Enviar</button>

</body>```
````

Comment: Podrias añadir el codigo que has usado para intentar resolver tu problema?, y explicar que es exactamente lo que te da error o no puedes solucionar?. Saludos

Comment: Puedes subir un fragmento de lo que has intentado, porque así parece que pides la resolución de una tarea.

Comment: @Daniel ahi subí una parte del codigo de lo que estaba probando

Comment: Hola. El código que subiste no es consistente con lo que planteas: Sólo aparecen 2 productos y hablas de 3. Dices que no puede exceder 100 y controlas que no pase de 1500. Adicionalmente, el método sumar está mal planteado porque va a sumar cada que algún input cambie, de modo que si alguno cambia tres veces acumulará esas veces el valor sin quitar lo que había sumado en el cambio anterior.

Comment: Adicionalmente, el evento change se produce cuando el input modificado pierde el foco. Si el cursor se mantiene en alguno no tendrás el efecto esperado. Considera usar keyUp o KeyPress y aprovecha los ids de los inputs para sumar los productos de las cantidades solicitadas por sus precios.

Comment: @quevedo ya se, es un ejemplo lo que dije. el codigo que pase es lo que pude encontrar y que se asemeja a lo que necesito lograr yo

Comment: @FelipeUrcia tu respuesta era buena ¿por qué la eliminaste?

Comment: Entonces debo concluir que aún no has intentado algo. Prueba con las sugerencias que hice en mi segundo comentario. Y, si no lo logras muestras el código en lugar de ese ejemplo. **Es grosero que hayas pegado algo que no has intentado**.

Comment: Hola @BetaM. Imagino que la eliminó como consecuencia de comprobar que estaba haciendo la tarea a OP, que reconoce no haber intentado algo diferente de pegar un ejemplo parecido, que además es incorrecto

Comment: @quevedo eso que pegue es lo que ya probe pero como no llego al resultado que necesito estoy pidiendo ayuda. ese codio es lo mas cercano que tengo por el momento a lo que quiero lograr

Comment: @quevedo mi codigo tiene mas de 2000 lineas no puedo hacerles la lista de todos los productos con los precios, les di una consigna de ejemplo y como me pidieron un ejemplo con código subí una parte de lo que tengo. si queres pasame tu contacto y te explico bien lo que necesito enseñándote todo el codigo si eso te ayuda. Gracias igualmente

Comment: @BetaM en realidad primero pensé que habría logrado comprender, y al final no logre comprender muy bien la consulta, quería darle una ayuda, pero al final no estoy seguro si pueda serle realmente útil. Pero gracias por la consideración, volveré a activarla, esperando sea de ayuda.

Comment: @BetaM Gracias por la ayuda. lo que necesito es que cuando un cliente indique que quiere 1 gaseosa el valor de "1" sea "50" para que pueda sumarlo y mostrarlo como precio de los productos elegidos y a esto agregarle una restricción máxima para que no supere ese precio

Comment: La respuesta que te ofrece @FelipeUrcia es perfecta. Nota que usa keyUp en lugar de change. Y que suma los tres valores, **sin acumular** sólo necesitas multiplicar cada valor por su precio dentro de la sumatoria.

Comment: @quevedo haaa ya entendi gracias y graciaaaas

Comment: y con el if le hago la restriccion del precio no?

Answer (score 1):

Te doy una idea como podrías acoplar tu código, usando onkeyup es una forma de hacerlo, esta se ejecuta cada que levantas el dedo de la tecla.

```js
function calcular(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
Dato 1 : <input onkeyup="calcular()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
Dato 2 : <input onkeyup="calcular()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Dato 3 : <input onkeyup="calcular()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```